# NodeJS | working with two protocols in server

Tags: javascript, node.js

i would like to work with http protocol and websocket on my server, and i will explain:

i have a chat app and i have a login page and chat page.
i would like to use the http protocol on login page and websocket for my chat page.

and if the answer yes, can i do this ?

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')

const app = express()

const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketio(server)

in.on('connection', (req,res) => {
  //...
})

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  //...
})

server.listen(port, (req, res) => {
  console.log('Server is listen on port ' + port)
})
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "page"? If you mean html page, then no, your chat page still needs to be loaded via http before the js inside the page can open a websocket connection. But other than that, yes, it'll work - did you try it?

Comment: yes, i tried this code and this works but i don't know if this code is acceptable for real project

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable. Of course for production projects, take a look at the "advanced topics" of the [expressjs docs](https://expressjs.com), and check back with your company's sysadmin, but it really is all you need for a start and won't change a lot with growth.